# How do I pretty-print an array?

Tags: json, symfony, twig

I have an array like this:

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
```

and I want to print it in a readble way like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

I have to pass the array to a Twig template. I tried this, but I don't get the result I want. Can you please advise me what do change?

In controller:

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
$b = json_encode($a);
$c = json_decode($b, true);

return $this->render('AcmeTestBundle:Home:data.html.twig', array('data' => $c));
```

In template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}

    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmetest/css/test.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ data }}

{% endblock %}
```

(this is base.html.twig: )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surround your array with `<pre>` tag. `<pre>{{ data }}</pre>`

Comment: I tried this (I changed my template's body to `<pre> {{ data }} </pre>`, if this is what I should do), but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: in your controller instead of passing array to data pass string that contains info you want like: `print_r($c, true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the Twig Debug Extensions:

**Twig 1.x**

```
<pre>{% debug data %}</pre>
```

**Twig 2.x**

```
{{ dump(user, categories) }}
```

The debug/dump tags only work when the `debug` environment option is set to `true`.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html

Also, you can try this without the debug extension:

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));

return $this->render('AcmeTestBundle:Home:data.html.twig', array('data' => var_export($a, true)));
```

Inside your template:

```
<pre>{{ data }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the dump function within your twig template.

Try this:

```
<pre>{{ dump(data) }}</pre>
```

That should do the trick without having to add an extension or print via your controller.

Comment: Natif, simple, perfect !

Comment: This only gives the methods. I'll like to see the class variables.

Answer (score 4):

Use [LadybugBundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle).

**Some key features:**

-Dump arrays, objects, a GD Image

-5 helpers that can be used in any controller

-Symfony commands

-Symfony profiler integration

-Twig Filter

I hope help.